# nRec vazia ao receber retorno da SEFAZ

Tags: php, array, xml, nfe

Utilizando a API do projeto NFePHP, através da função:

```
$retorno = $nfe->sefazEnviaLote($aXml, $tpAmb, $idLote, $aResposta, $indSinc, $flagZip);
```

obtenho o array `$aResposta`.

Contudo este array está retornando a tag `nRec` vazia. Segue abaixo XML e o retorno do array.

XML da pasta `temporárias`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <env:Header/>
  <env:Body>
    <nfeAutorizacaoLoteResult xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeAutorizacao">
      <retEnviNFe versao="3.10" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
        <verAplic>GO3.0</verAplic>
        <cStat>104</cStat>
        <xMotivo>Lote processado</xMotivo>
        <cUF>52</cUF>
        <dhRecbto>2017-01-12T11:45:40-02:00</dhRecbto>
        <protNFe versao="3.10">
          <infProt>
            <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
            <verAplic>GO3.0</verAplic>
            <chNFe>52170119811185000142550010000000361385289826</chNFe>
            <dhRecbto>2017-01-12T11:45:40-02:00</dhRecbto>
            <nProt>152170016903387</nProt>
            <digVal>N3MSuIoDpO8EIi032j56zhQ+hTU=</digVal>
            <cStat>100</cStat>
            <xMotivo>Autorizado o uso da NF-e</xMotivo>
          </infProt>
        </protNFe>
      </retEnviNFe>
    </nfeAutorizacaoLoteResult>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Retorno do array `$aResposta`:

```
 Array ( 
    [bStat] => 1 
    [versao] => 3.10 
    [tpAmb] => 2 
    [verAplic] => GO3.0 
    [cStat] => 104 
    [xMotivo] => Lote processado 
    [cUF] => 52 
    [dhRecbto] => 2017-01-12T11:45:40-02:00 
    [tMed] => 
    [nRec] => 
    [prot] => 
        Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [chNFe] => 52170119811185000142550010000000361385289826 
                [dhRecbto] => 2017-01-12T11:45:40-02:00 
                [nProt] => 152170016903387 
                [digVal] => N3MSuIoDpO8EIi032j56zhQ+hTU= 
                [cStat] => 100 
                [xMotivo] => Autorizado o uso da NF-e 
            ) 
    )
)
```

Ou seja, não consigo consultar o número de recibo utilizando a função:

```
$nfe->sefazConsultaRecibo($recibo, $tpAmb, $aResposta);
```

Contudo, consigo imprimir a DANF-e normalmente...

Comment: O número do recibo está nesse array? que puseste? Já recebes esse array e está ok?7

Comment: O número de recibo está vazio. @Miguel

Comment: Ha percebo, mas deveria vir desse xml? É que nos xml também não há

Comment: Sim, deveria. Podemos ir para o chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51669/nrec-vazia-ao-receber-retorno-da-sefaz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom dia, você não tem o número do recibo porque deve estar usando o parâmetro `$indSinc` igual a 1 (modo síncrono), desta forma a autorização da NF-e é instantânea, não é gerado Lote de NF-e nem número de recibo, por isso o `nRec` fica vazio.

Se você alterar o parâmetro `$indSinc` para 0 (modo assíncrono) aí sim o webservice da SEFAZ vai gerar um Lote de NF-e e te retornar apenas o número do recibo, para depois de alguns segundos você consultar o Lote, pelo número do recibo.

Answer (score 2):

A variável `$indSinc` estava setada com valor '1', ou seja SERVIÇO SÍNCRONO, bastando então alterar para '0'.

a) Serviços síncronos – o processamento da solicitação de serviço é concluído na mesma conexão, com a devolução de uma mensagem com o resultado do processamento do serviço solicitado;

b) Serviços assíncronos – o processamento da solicitação de serviço não é concluído na mesma conexão, havendo a **devolução de uma mensagem de resposta com um recibo** que apenas confirma o recebimento da solicitação de serviço. O aplicativo do contribuinte deverá realizar uma nova conexão para consultar o resultado do processamento do serviço solicitado anteriormente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.: o processamento SÍNCRONO depende fortemente da infraestrutura de processamento das Secretarias de Fazenda Estaduais.

O processamento ASSÍNCRONO tem maior tempo de resposta devido ao ciclo de envio do XML, que até sua autorização pode passar por mais um *WebService*.

Referência:

Projeto Nota Fiscal Eletrônica. **Manual de Integração - Contribuinte
Padrões Técnicos de Comunicação**. https://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/nfe/downloads/Manual_de_Integracao_Contribuinte_versao_111-2006-05-30.pdf

Grupos do Google: NFePHP. **nRec vazio ao receber retorno** https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nfephp/6yEs8WDJWvE

Grupos do Google: NFePHP. **Autoriza (síncrono x assíncrono)**. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nfephp/qkqOd6Lqt1U

XProcess. **Testes entre Método Síncrono e Assíncrono na NFC-e** http://www.xprocess.com.br/novo/?p=5306